# openssl_encrypt works for some strings and dont work other

Tags: php

Why is it that `openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_NO_PADDING);` works in some cases and dont work in some.

**This is the code:**

```
<?php
$cipher = 'AES-256-ECB';
$key = 'd61d2cd58d01b234e1800938erf8467k';
$plaintext = $entityBody;
if (strlen($plaintext) % 8) {
    $plaintext = str_pad($plaintext, strlen($plaintext) + 8 - strlen($plaintext) % 8, "\0");    
}
$chiperRaw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_NO_PADDING);    
$ciphertext = trim(base64_encode($chiperRaw));  
?>
```

**For Example:**

it doesnt work for this: `index12=123&date=2021-07-20&TKP=TKP&SA=SA&TPP=TPP`

and it works for this : `index12=123&date=2021-07-20&TKP=TKP&Snd=Snd&SA=SA&TPP=TPP`

again it doesnt work for this: `index12=123&date=2021-07-20&TKP=TKP&Snd=Snd&GSS=GSS&SA=SA&TPP=TPP`

and works for this : `index12=123&date=2021-07-20&TKP=TKP&Snd=Snd&GSS=GSS&LI=LI&SA=SA&TPP=TPP&XM=XM`

**how to get rid of this issue ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as though the block size should be 16 and not 8 bytes.

```
if (strlen($plaintext) % 16) {
    $plaintext = str_pad($plaintext, strlen($plaintext) + 16 - strlen($plaintext) % 16, "\0");
}
```